# “I always work out except (on) Monday”

Tags: prepositions

What’s the difference between these?

1. I always work out except Monday.
2. I always work out except on Monday.

Is it just a matter of style?

Comment: I do agree with the first answer.
Besides, if you tell me ‘I always work out except Monday’, it means to me you don’t work out on **the** Monday of the week we currently are.
As such, I’d either say ‘I always work out except on Monday’ or ‘I always work out except (on) Monday**s**’

Comment: The first answer is better, the second one sounds awkward

Comment: Agree with @Sean213 that "Mondays" more clearly conveys that you are talking about Mondays in general. But in a context where somebody is discussing their weekly routine, in a casual style, either of the original sentences might be acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"On Monday" is acceptable.  "Except Monday" is odd, because it is in contrast to "I" or "work-out".  And how can a day be constructed with either word.

You probably don't mean "I always work out".  That would mean continuously.  You probably mean "I work out every day except Monday".

Now in that sentence, you don't need "on" because Monday is contrasted with "every day", which is fine.

Comment: Yes, I mean “I work out every day except Monday”, thank you.

Comment: Can I say “I sit on any couch, except this couch”? Or should I say “I sit on any couch, except on this couch”?

Comment: @Gabriel It would be the first, except you'd be more likely to say "I'll sit on any couch except this one."

Comment: @Gabriel You wouldn’t usually repeat the preposition twice, as it’s redundant.